# Qtouch with non-Atmel microcontrollers

Tags: stm32, atmel, capacitive, qtouch

Simple question really.  Can I use Atmels `Qtouch` library with non-Atmel MCUs (such as an STM32)?

It seems like Atmel has a solid line of capacitive touch ICs, which come coupled with an API library for interfacing with them.

Answer (score 0):

No, because it is not released as source code but as precompiled binary library object. Fortunately ST has a similar touch sensing library you might want to use instead on an STM32.

Comment: thanks - after reading the datasheet for atmels ICs I figure I can write my own library . Too bad thats the case though...